# Get the current height of video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I can't understand what is cutting the height of video. When I look in to dev tool - it show's me that the height of video is 384px, but when geting it I have 342px

Tried something like this, but it's return me the natural height, not the current

```
$("#right-top-box video").bind("loadedmetadata", function () {
  var height = this.videoHeight;
});
```

How can I get the current height of video?

http://beardhouse.com.ua/#/informacia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run directly in the Chrome js console: `$('video').innerHeight();`

You will see that with innerHeight you can calculate the height of the video correctly.

[image]

**EDIT**

Try wrapping the function inside

$(window).load(function() {

});

in order to wait for all media to load.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, the height is still 342

Comment: When i open that site I get an alert '461' but as you can see from the screenshot.

Comment: yes you are right - in console it's give me what i need, but using innerHeight in editor I stell have 342

Comment: Can I see some of your code? Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: I suspect that you are executing that function before all media are loaded. Try to wrap that function inside $(window).load(function() {
    
});

Comment: Oh happy to help, glad it works :) I have just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
var videoActualWidth = video.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var videoActualHeight = video.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Comment: this method does not output any values

Comment: The method you are using appears fine and i hope you are adding it before the video has loaded as it is loadedmetadata event.